# php captcha is not working properly

Tags: php

i m getting this error on mozilla

> "The image
>   “*****/form%20and%20its%20validation/New%20folder/captcha/captcha.php”
>   cannot be displayed because it contains errors."

fonts.ttf is in the same folder.

and this code showing nothing on chrome. what is wrong in this code?

i want to include this in my form page ..

```
$rnum='';

//generating random number
$rnum = rand(100000,9999999);

//creating image with size 300*60
$imgo = imagecreatetruecolor(300,60);

$white = imagecolorallocate($imgo, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($imgo, 128, 128, 128);
$red = imagecolorallocate($imgo, 200, 100,90);
$black = imagecolorallocate($imgo, 0, 0, 0);

imagefilledrectangle($imgo, 0, 0, 200, 35, $black);

//getting font  

$cfont= 'font.ttf'; 

imagettftext($imgo, 35, 0, 22, 24, $red, $cfont, $rnum);

header ("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($imgo);
imagedestroy($imgo);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is 99% because an error in the script which get's printed to the browser, **too**.

You can capture the error and print it instead of the corrupt image:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', true);
ini_set('xmlrpc_errors', true);
ob_start();
$rnum='';

//generating random number
$rnum = rand(100000,9999999);

//creating image with size 300*60
$imgo = imagecreatetruecolor(300,60);

$white = imagecolorallocate($imgo, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($imgo, 128, 128, 128);
$red = imagecolorallocate($imgo, 200, 100,90);
$black = imagecolorallocate($imgo, 0, 0, 0);

imagefilledrectangle($imgo, 0, 0, 200, 35, $black);

//getting font  

$cfont= 'font.ttf'; 

imagettftext($imgo, 35, 0, 22, 24, $red, $cfont, $rnum);
$errors = ob_get_clean();
ob_end();
if ($errors) {
    echo $errors;
} else {
    header ("Content-type: image/png");
    imagepng($imgo);
}

imagedestroy($imgo);
```

If it doesn't work or help, you can simply remove `header ("Content-type: image/png");` from your script and then try again.